# Numpy ndarray in a for loop does not change

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I have this problem with numpy ndarrays in a loop.
Basically, I have two matrices, b and c, and I need to generate some matrix, a, that is the same as b, however, it has 0 when c's elements are above some thresholds which are collected in the x list.

It seems that this simple code really just works for the first iteration, but I can't understand why.

```
b = np.random.rand(3,2)
c = np.random.rand(3,2)

x = [0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
for i in x:
   a = b
   a[np.where(c >= i)] = 0
```

Edit: here's a print of what I get

```
b: [[0.48514708 0.12340482]
 [0.84212494 0.63737198]
 [0.72264245 0.39808082]] 

c: [[0.54775772 0.35079886]
 [0.87601791 0.18765178]
 [0.47789123 0.60977198]]

i=0.5 
 [[0.         0.12340482]
 [0.         0.63737198]
 [0.72264245 0.        ]] 

i=0.6 
 [[0.         0.12340482]
 [0.         0.63737198]
 [0.72264245 0.        ]] 

i=0.7 
 [[0.         0.12340482]
 [0.         0.63737198]
 [0.72264245 0.        ]]
```

The resulting a matrices are all equal. On the contrary I expected

```
i=0.6 
 [[0.48514708 0.12340482]
 [0.          0.63737198]
 [0.72264245  0.]]

i=0.7
[[0.48514708 0.12340482]
 [0.         0.63737198]
 [0.72264245 0.39808082]]
```

Comment: `a=b` doesn't do anything significant.  This loop changes `b`, not a copy of it.

Comment: But i don't want b to be changed. So how can I set for every loop iteration a copy of b such that it's the copy that get changed and not b?

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj said, the line a=b doesn't really do anything and the loop changes b not a copy of it. Thus simply changing the line

```
a=b
```

with

```
a = np.copy(b)
```

solves the problem.